# Referencing (loading) a generic type from its name in a WCF Svc markup file

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, typeloadexception

In a WCF Svc markup file, I would like to use a generic type as a factory :

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Factory="MY_GENERIC_TYPE_GOES_HERE" Service="WebSrv.MyService" CodeBehind="MyService.svc.cs" %>
```

The definition of my generic class is like this :

```
namespace Tools.Services
{
   public class ServiceHostFactory<TService> : System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactoryBase
   {
          //...
   }
}
```

How can I reference this type with a given Type as the template type, I mean something like this :

```
Tools.Services.ServiceHostFactory<WebSrv.MyService>
```

By looking at the [MSDN Type.GetType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) documentation, I tried the following with no luck :

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WebSrv.MyService" Factory="Tools.Services.ServiceHostFactory`1[WebSrv.MyService]"  CodeBehind="MyService.svc.cs" %>
```

Output:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Parser Error Description: An error
>   occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this
>   request. Please review the following specific parse error details and
>   modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The CLR Type
>   'Tools.Services.ServiceHostFactory`1[WebSrv.MyService]'
>   could not be loaded during service compilation. Verify that this type
>   is either defined in a source file located in the application's
>   \App_Code directory, contained in a compiled assembly located in the
>   application's \bin directory, or present in an assembly installed in
>   the Global Assembly Cache. Note that the type name is case-sensitive
>   and that the directories such as \App_Code and \bin must be located
>   in the application's root directory and cannot be nested in
>   subdirectories.

Output:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Tools.Services' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WebSrv.MyService" Factory="Tools.Services.ServiceHostFactory`1[WebSrv.MyService,WebSrv ],Tools.Services"  CodeBehind="MyService.svc.cs" %>
```

Output:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Tools.Services' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.

Is this even possible to achieve in a generic way ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer :
I had to use **double brackets** here.
And because two types from **two different assemblies** were involved, I had to fully qualified each of them the following way :

```
Tools.Services.ServiceHostFactory`1[[WebSrv.MyService, WebSrv]], Tools.Services
```

Hope this will help someone.